# Restore fstab with correct UUID so that I can boot with crypto_LUKS partition

Tags: boot, luks, fstab

I ended up with this error upon boot:

```
Welcome to GRUB!

error: no such cryptodisk found.
error: disk 'cryptouuid/6e0637...' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> _
```

And when I boot live USB and run `sudo lsblk -f` - I get this:

```
NAME                        FSTYPE            FSVER  UUID
...
sda
  - sda1             
  - sda4                    crypto_LUKS       1           6e0637...
    - luks-6e0637...        ext4                1.0       082f44...
...
```

And when I do `cat etc/fstab` of the original Linux installation - I get only this:

```
UUID=082f44...        /       ext4        acl,user_xattr        0       1
```

=====

It looks like it's searching for the wrong UUID ...
So - does that mean that if I restore fstab file - I'll be able to boot? ... And if so - what should I put there?

Comment: At least you'll have to reinstall GRUB. What did you do to trigger that problem?

Comment: I had dual boot between Windows and Linux (in this order on the SSD) and wanted to expand the windows partition. So I used some dumb windows program to do this job. However - the attempt failed and after that I just couldn't boot my laptop.

Comment: I ended up re-installing. + - I swore to never user Shitows again! ... (And by the way, a guy in the Manjaro forums offered a solution but by the time I saw it - it was too late. ... Also I had deadline at work so I couldn't spend more time.)